# Alphabetical list/index for custom tags -> even if empty - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, list, tags, indexing, alphabetical

In wordpress (3.4) I created some code which returns an alphabetical list/index of custom tags and filters the custom posts in a grid layout. The tags are named as "tagdirectory". The custom post is named "directory".

This is the code:

```
<?php $list = ''; 
$tags = get_terms( 'tagdirectory' ); 
echo '<ul id="portfolio-filter">'; 
echo'<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';
$groups = array();
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
$first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
$groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;}
if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
$list .= "\n\t" . '<h2>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) .'</h2>';
$list .= "\n\t" . '<ul>';
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
$lower = strtolower($tag->name);
$name = str_replace(' ', ' ', $tag->name);
$naam = str_replace(' ', '-', $lower);
$list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a href="#'.$naam.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';
}}}}else $list .= "\n\t" . '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';print $list;
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

This works perfectly but I would also like for empty letters from the alphabet to be shown.

For example, now it returns:

A

Aicher Otl

Apeloig Philippe

B

Bass Saul

F

Fitszimmons Maureen

... and so on

But it doesn't show the empty letter groups because there are no tags starting with this letter. I do need it to show the capital letter for empty groups though, like so:

A

Aicher Otl

Apeloig Philippe

B

Bass Saul

C

D

E

F

Fitszimmons Maureen

G

... and so on

Can anybody help me and tell me what code I should add for this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have just edited this solution> http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2010/12/03/template-to-list-posts-by-first-letter-of-title/

I got it to display a custom post type by changing the 'post-type' on line #37 to the correct custom taxonomy ('distributors' as I am using to list companies by name) and it's done the trick.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: A-Z Pages

A WordPress template to list page titles by first letter.

You should modify the CSS to suit your theme and place it in its proper file.
Be sure to set the $posts_per_row and $posts_per_page variables.
*/
$posts_per_row = 3;
$posts_per_page = 15;
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<style type="text/css">
.letter-group { width: 100%; }
.letter-cell { width: 5%; height: 2em; text-align: center; padding-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; background: #e0e0e0; float: left; }
.row-cells { width: 70%; float: right; margin-right: 180px; }
.title-cell { width: 30%;  float: left; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 8px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
</style>

<div id="main-background">

   <div id="main-column">
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

      <div class="margin-top"></div>

      <div id="a-z">

         <?php
         $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
         $args = array (
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'paged' => $paged
         );
         query_posts($args);
         if ( have_posts() ) {
            $in_this_row = 0;
            while ( have_posts() ) {
               the_post();
               $first_letter = strtoupper(substr(apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title),0,1));
               if ($first_letter != $curr_letter) {
                  if (++$post_count > 1) {
                     end_prev_letter();
                  }
                  start_new_letter($first_letter);
                  $curr_letter = $first_letter;
               }
               if (++$in_this_row > $posts_per_row) {
                  end_prev_row();
                  start_new_row();
                  ++$in_this_row;  // Account for this first post
               } ?>
               <div class="title-cell"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            <?php }
            end_prev_letter();
            ?>
            <div class="navigation">
               <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Higher Letters') ?></div>
               <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Lower Letters &raquo;') ?></div>
            </div>
         <?php } else {
            echo "<h2>Sorry, no posts were found!</h2>";
         }
         ?>

      </div><!-- End id='a-z' -->

   </div><!-- End class='margin-top -->

</div><!-- End id='rightcolumn' -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<?php
function end_prev_letter() {
   end_prev_row();
   echo "</div><!-- End of letter-group -->\n";
   echo "<div class='clear'></div>\n";
}
function start_new_letter($letter) {
   echo "<div class='letter-group'>\n";
   echo "\t<div class='letter-cell'>$letter</div>\n";
   start_new_row($letter);
}
function end_prev_row() {
   echo "\t</div><!-- End row-cells -->\n";
}
function start_new_row() {
   global $in_this_row;
   $in_this_row = 0;
   echo "\t<div class='row-cells'>\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.